# Delete Transaction Records from Netsuite

Tags: transactions, netsuite, journal

Does anybody have any sort of experience deleting test transaction records from Netsuite. Right now what I can see is, going to each customer record and delete specific Sales Orders/CashSales/Journals which is a quite painful task(with large volume of data). Is there any other way that I'm unaware of ? Any help would be appreciated.

**EDIT :** 
The scenario here being mentioned is for production environment. Where we do have some test customers and transaction records which are impacting the Financial reports. So we want to get rid of all these test data(which is quite large).

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can delete multiple records at once by using inline editing, see the documentation [here](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_N353700.html) (NetSuite login required):

> To delete field data by editing inline:
>
> Enable the Edit button on the search results of the data containing
> the fields you want to delete.
>
> Select an editable element, in the first row, then hold down the Shift key and select the same element in the last row.
>
> While all of those fields in the column are highlighted, choose delete from the menu on the left. You can also set your segment size higher in Home > Set Preferences, to do more than 50 at a time.

Another option is to write a [Mass Update](https://system.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=chapter_N2992187.html) script, here is a very basic example:

```
function perform_update(rec_type, rec_id) {
    try {
        nlapiDeleteRecord(rec_type, rec_id);
    } catch(err) {
        nlapiLogExecution('DEBUG', 'Error deleting record', 'type = ' + rec_type + ", id = " + rec_id);
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess Mass update is not a suitable choice for this, since it might failed in case the record has some dependent records. Inline delete is a better option but the same rule applied for this also.

Comment: You could add some sophistication to the mass update script to identify and delete the dependant records first. Or, you could just 'brute force' your way by running it on all the record types separately until you don't get any more results :-)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend writing a scheduled script, and pull the dependent records first before deleting a master transaction, and then delete the most dependent transactions first.

EG: to delete Sales Order, You prefer deleting Invoice, Cash Sale, Customer payment and Applied Credit Memo/Journal Entries first. And you should prefer deleting Journals/Credit Memo/Customer Payment first then Invoice and then Sales Order itself.

If the search result does not give any dependent records, then you can delete the master transaction directly.

Comment: Since we're not given with any parameter to judge the test data. For me to ease my work I preferred to go through customer first as I can have a better track of  all his opportunities, sales orders/cashsales/invoices and journals. Again, I have to make sure that any of these deletion shouldn't impact on any financial reports as its a production environment. Which just increased my burden.

Comment: Pity that NetSuite doesn't have an "ON DELETE CASCADE" option (even though the DBMS that it runs on does).

Comment: actually NetSuite hides the complexity of DB model from us, a same record information could be stored across multiple tables (eg: on transactions you see line items, shipping info, transaction details, etc. which may be stored across different tables), probably CASCADE might be too complex for some of their back end logic.

Comment: @prasun, @ Klitos Kyriacou After having some query I got to know, it is never ever a delete case for transaction in production environment as it could impact the account entries and lead to improper accounting. The alternative way I suggested from one of colleague is that, we can make those test transaction void with some journal posting so even if the test transactions are there it won't affect your financial reports.

Comment: yeah, thats a wiser decision. Also, the new release allows you to write plugins to program the G/L entries. I haven't tried that but, might be useful if you want to post the amount to some dummy registers.

Comment: @prasun Sounds cool. Could you please hook me up with the link so I can explore it in more detail.

Comment: Read this topic "Custom GL Lines Plug-in Overview" in Help